# Simple JavaScript Animation for 1 Second to Highlight Text?

Tags: javascript

I searched by google but I found that much I can't overview it all, so I need your experience:

I need to highlight a text for 1 second. For example a simple "blink"-effect with a color or something like that.

I tried JQuery-Animation allready but it seems very bugged with newer versions of Firefox / Internet Explorer.

So do you have an idea?

Comment: Define "newer versions"?  Describe the bug?  Are you already using JQuery?

Comment: Do you have any reference sites? Or is it something like the one on SO, e.g. the highlight effect when you click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103519/what-is-the-worst-source-control-you-have-used/1103531#1103531 ?

Comment: I am using jQuery the bug is, that the highlight stucks many times (sometimes in the middle, sometimes it never appear). It seems to hang up. Newer Versions = I see that bugs at IE8 & FF3

Comment: @OKW such an highlight would be completly enough

Comment: No offense intended, but usually the good JavaScript libraries are well-tested even on the newest beta browsers and in most cases the bug lies in the code of the user.

Comment: Yeh, Kovu, let's see some code. What's breaking? It may just be your code... (no offence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function highlightFor(id,color,seconds){
    var element = document.getElementById(id)
    var origcolor = element.style.backgroundColor
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
       element.style.backgroundColor = origcolor;
    },(seconds*1000));
}
```

should work. Supply it with the id of the element, the highlight color and the time you want the highlight to display for (in seconds). For example

```
highlightFor('object','yellow',3);
```

EDIT: As far as colours set in stylesheets is concerned, I strongly suggest using a javascript library (like jQuery). I know you say that you've had some problems with it, but it's most likely there's a tiny bug in the code you've written that's giving you that opinion. Just ask on SO if you have any questions about jQuery!

Comment: looks good, but it only set the bgcolor, isn't it? How can I build a nice effect for this second?

Comment: You might want to save `document.getElementById(id)` so you don't have to do three searches. Also, how about using the `var` statement to declare variables (e.g. `origColor`). Also `origColor` will only work if the original color is set inline... what if it's set in a StyleSheet?

Answer (score 0):

look for setTimeout() which executes a code some time in the future and clearTimeout() which cancels the setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

```
var h = document.getElementById("highlight");
window.onload = function () {
  // when the page loads, set the background to red
  h.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";

  // after 1 second (== 1000ms)
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    // ...revert this, use the original color
    h.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }, 1000);
};
```