# animate text highlighting

Tags: javascript, animation

I would like to simulate the effect of a highlighter going over a block of text. I'd love for it to be a little fuzzy also but I will be happy to settle for a straight line. Is there something out there? or a good starting point for me to build something? Thanks

To be clearer I want the user to see the effect of the highlighter moving over the text character by character, left to right, top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this post [Simple JavaScript Animation for 1 Second to Highlight Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818882/simple-javascript-animation-for-1-second-to-highlight-text)

Answer (score 0):

look at http://www.tripbase.com/code/highlightTutorial.html

Comment: That's going to cause a lot of problems if there's events attached to the elements within the parent element being searched on. It's best to avoid innerHTML (and the like) for applications this broad.

Answer (score 0):

[Highlight effect as stackverflow](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptDemo/TextEffectshighlight.htm)

[highlight effect as firefox search bar](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

i think can be done with jquery or ajax...not very understand your question..