# How to synchronize and highlight HTML text to audio

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I want to highlight the text as audio plays in a web site.
As the audio plays this text will keep on highlighting, just as we see in television.

Please tell me  how i can do this using any web technology.

I will be very thankful to all of you.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: impossible with such low-level languages

Comment: have a look at this http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/video/track/index.html

Comment: Do you have the text and the time when each portion of text must be displayed? How is audio played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a question similar to this one here that answers your question on how to highlight text:
[Simple JavaScript Animation for 1 Second to Highlight Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818882/simple-javascript-animation-for-1-second-to-highlight-text)

HTML5 is good for audio:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

These resources will hopefully get you on the right track!

Comment: i think he wants to sync the highlighting to the audio

Comment: I want to highlight text just like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/42fcd5el1vscd0l/wire-frame-2%281%29.jpg?dl=0
as audio plays...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own vtt file with the captions (text) you need. Then link it to the audio code like so:

```
    <audio src="sampleaudiofile.ogg">
      <track kind="captions" src="sampleaudiofile.en.vtt" srclang="en" label="English">
    </audio>
```

**[This link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webvtt/)** from the w3c specs shows an example of vtt format and how to do it.